# value error when using 1d array for curve fitting

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, curve-fitting, valueerror

I am getting this error when using Scipy curve fitting to get the fitting parameters (A,B,C,D). There is no problem with defined function and works well and responds well. There is also no problem when the x (x11, x22) and y array (used for curve fitting) are just one element array and not 1d array with some elements. I know that this problem is because of multi elements in the input array for fitting (x11, x22, y). Actually, I think it is because the code does not know to which element of array should apply  the condition in the function. but, I do not how to solve it. Any help and suggestion would be appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
x11=fin[:,0]
x22=fin[:,1]
y=fin[:,2]

bin=[4,4.5,5,5.5]


def interpo(x,A,B, C, D):
    x1, x2=x
    if  bin[0] <= x1 <bin[1]:
        if np.logical_and(x2>= bin[0] , x2<bin[1]):
            f1=A + ((x1 -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
            f2=A + ((x2 -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
            kh=f2/f1
        if x2>= bin[1] and x2<bin[2]:
            f1=A + ((x1 -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
            f2=B + ((x2 -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
            kh=f2/f1
            
        if x2>= bin[2] and x2<bin[3]:
            f1=A + ((x1 -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
            f2=C + ((x2 -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
            kh=f2/f1
    if x1>= bin[1] and x1<bin[2]:
        if x2>= bin[1] and x2<bin[2]:
            f1=B + ((x1 -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
            f2=B + ((x2 -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
            kh=f2/f1
        if x2>= bin[2] and x2<bin[3]:
            f1=B + ((x1 -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
            f2=C + ((x2 -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
            kh=f2/f1
    if x1>= bin[2] and x1<bin[3]:
        if x2>= bin[2] and x2<bin[3]:
            f1=C + ((x1 -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
            f2=C + ((x2 -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
            kh=f2/f1
            
    return (kh)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(interpo, (x11,x22), y, method='lm')
```

And here is the error:

```
      Input In [3] in interpo
    if  bin[0] <= x1 <bin[1]:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Indeed it is not clear how the condition should be applied to the elements of the array. If you explain what you want to happen, it is possible to provide an answer.

Comment: You are right, I want to give an x array and the function should calculate the result for each element in the arrays based on A,B,C,D. Then these results will fitted by y array to give the A,B, C,D parameters. I do not how to say that the conditions should be checked for all elements in the array.

Comment: `curve_fit` passes the entire `x11` to `interpo` and expects it to return an according array to be compared with `x22`. This usually fails on `if`s. Easy workaround is to check for arrays and program the iteration yourself, or `numpy.piecewise` may help, as the input allows arrays. The `x1 x2` decomposition would need some extra thought, though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to evaluate the values in `x` one by one, you can use the following function:

```py
def interpo(x, A, B, C, D):
    result = []
    for x1, x2 in zip(x[0], x[1]):
        if  bin[0] <= x1 <bin[1]:
            if np.logical_and(x2>= bin[0] , x2<bin[1]):
                f1=A + ((x1 -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
                f2=A + ((x2 -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
                kh=f2/f1
            if x2>= bin[1] and x2<bin[2]:
                f1=A + ((x1 -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
                f2=B + ((x2 -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
                kh=f2/f1
                
            if x2>= bin[2] and x2<bin[3]:
                f1=A + ((x1 -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
                f2=C + ((x2 -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
                kh=f2/f1
        if x1>= bin[1] and x1<bin[2]:
            if x2>= bin[1] and x2<bin[2]:
                f1=B + ((x1 -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
                f2=B + ((x2 -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
                kh=f2/f1
            if x2>= bin[2] and x2<bin[3]:
                f1=B + ((x1 -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
                f2=C + ((x2 -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
                kh=f2/f1
        if x1>= bin[2] and x1<bin[3]:
            if x2>= bin[2] and x2<bin[3]:
                f1=C + ((x1 -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
                f2=C + ((x2 -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
                kh=f2/f1
        result.append(kh)        
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I though again and for the purpose of fitting this function, it seems to need to process numpy arrays freely, so I would suggest to rewrite it like this as an alternative:

```py
def interpo(x, A, B, C, D):
    x1, x2 = x
    temp = np.zeros((x1.shape[0], 3))
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[0], x1 < bin[1]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[0], x2 < bin[1])
    temp[cond, 0] = A + ((x1[cond] -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
    temp[cond, 1] = A + ((x2[cond] -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[0], x1 < bin[1]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[1], x2 < bin[2])
    temp[cond, 0] = A + ((x1[cond] -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
    temp[cond, 1] = B + ((x2[cond] -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[0], x1 < bin[1]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[2], x2 < bin[3])
    temp[cond, 0] = A + ((x1[cond] -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
    temp[cond, 1] = C + ((x2[cond] -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[1], x1 < bin[2]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[1], x2 < bin[2])
    temp[cond, 0] = B + ((x1[cond] -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
    temp[cond, 1] = B + ((x2[cond] -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[1], x1 < bin[2]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[2], x2 < bin[3])
    temp[cond, 0] = B + ((x1[cond] -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
    temp[cond, 1] = C + ((x2[cond] -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[2], x1 < bin[3]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[2], x2 < bin[3])
    temp[cond, 0] = C + ((x1[cond] -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
    temp[cond, 1] = C + ((x2[cond] -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)

    temp[:,2] = np.divide(temp[:,0], temp[:,1])
            
    return temp[:,2]
```

But `curve_fit()` seems unable to fit the parameters for this function. See the code below:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x11 = np.random.uniform(0.0, 3.0, 100)
x22 = np.random.beta(2.3, 4.8, 100) * 3.0

x11_int = x11.astype(np.int64)
x22_int = x22.astype(np.int64)

x22[x22_int < x11_int] = x22[x22_int < x11_int] + 1.0
x11_int = x11.astype(np.int64)
x22_int = x22.astype(np.int64)
x22[x22_int < x11_int] = x22[x22_int < x11_int] + 1.0
x11 = x11 / 2.0 + 4.0
x22 = x22 / 2.0 + 4.0

def interpo(x, A, B, C, D):
    x1, x2 = x
    temp = np.zeros((x1.shape[0], 3))
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[0], x1 < bin[1]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[0], x2 < bin[1])
    temp[cond, 0] = A + ((x1[cond] -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
    temp[cond, 1] = A + ((x2[cond] -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[0], x1 < bin[1]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[1], x2 < bin[2])
    temp[cond, 0] = A + ((x1[cond] -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
    temp[cond, 1] = B + ((x2[cond] -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[0], x1 < bin[1]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[2], x2 < bin[3])
    temp[cond, 0] = A + ((x1[cond] -bin[0])/(bin[1]-bin[0]))*(B-A)
    temp[cond, 1] = C + ((x2[cond] -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[1], x1 < bin[2]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[1], x2 < bin[2])
    temp[cond, 0] = B + ((x1[cond] -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
    temp[cond, 1] = B + ((x2[cond] -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[1], x1 < bin[2]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[2], x2 < bin[3])
    temp[cond, 0] = B + ((x1[cond] -bin[1])/(bin[2]-bin[1]))*(C-B)
    temp[cond, 1] = C + ((x2[cond] -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
    
    cond = np.logical_and(x1 >= bin[2], x1 < bin[3]) & np.logical_and(x2 >= bin[2], x2 < bin[3])
    temp[cond, 0] = C + ((x1[cond] -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)
    temp[cond, 1] = C + ((x2[cond] -bin[2])/(bin[3]-bin[2]))*(D-C)

    temp[:,2] = np.divide(temp[:,0], temp[:,1])
            
    return (temp[:,2])

bin=[4,4.5,5,5.5]

y=interpo((x11, x22), 4.2, 0.9, 3.7, 11.0)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(interpo, (x11, x22), y, method='lm')

print(popt)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually i think the problem was that I had not added a for loop in the function. I added the for loop as @dkruit suggested and the problem solved.